# performanceCounter hang when using VS 2012 + IIsExpress8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express, performancecounter

I'm trying to figure this one out since a couple of days, so I came up with a test case :

- start a new asp.net mvc project
- on the HomeController.Index replace the code by

  var test = new PerformanceCounter("toto", "cac");
   return Content("toto");
- Make sure it's set for using IIS Express
- Launch the project on debug

On my machine it hangs for ever on the PerformanceCounter line. If I it the stop button, I can see the following statcktrace :

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(string name, object defaultValue, bool doNotExpand, bool checkSecurity) + 0x5ae bytes 
mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(string name) + 0x29 bytes 
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(string item) + 0x67 bytes  
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(string item) + 0xbb bytes    
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryTable.get() + 0x6a bytes    
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(string category, string counter, ref bool categoryExists) + 0x1a bytes    
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(string machine, string category, string counter) + 0x4f bytes 
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl() + 0x2eb bytes 
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.PerformanceCounter(string categoryName, string counterName, string instanceName, bool readOnly) + 0x98 bytes   
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.PerformanceCounter(string categoryName, string counterName) + 0x13 bytes
```

> TestPerfCounter.dll!TestPerfCounter.Controllers.HomeController.Index() Line 17 + 0x21 bytes C#

Any idea ? If I switch to development server it doesn't hang ...

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

I don't know why , but it solves

> Rebuild the base performance counters
>
> Extensible counter information is stored in both of the following
>   locations: The following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current
>   Version\Perflib\009 The %Systemroot%\System32\Perfc009.dat file and
>   the %Systemroot%\System32\Perfh009.dat file To rebuild the base
>   performance counter libraries manually, follow these steps: Expand the
>   Perfc009.dat file and the Perfh009.dat file. These files are located
>   on the Windows Installation Disc. The compressed files are found at
>   DriveLetter:\i386\perfc009.da_ and at DriveLetter:\i386\perfh009.da_.
>   Replace the files that are in the %Systemroot%\System32 folder. Start
>   Registry Editor, and then locate the following key in the registry:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib In the registry, change the Last Counter
>   value to 1846 (decimal), and change the Last Help value to 1847
>   (decimal). Locate the following registry key to search for services
>   that have a Performancesubkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services Remove the
>   following values from the Performance subkey (if they exist): First
>   Counter First Help Last Counter Last Help You can also use the
>   Exctrlst.exe tool to locate the performance counter dynamic-link
>   library files (DLLs) that are installed, and then access the registry
>   to remove the DWORD values. You now have a workable performance
>   registry that contains only system base counters.
>
> Note Removing the values from the Performance subkey in the registry
>   may cause any installed .NET Framework applications not to work the
>   next time that they are started. If this occurs, use the lodctr /R
>   command in the "Re-add the extensible counters" section to rebuild the
>   Performance counters. If you continue to have problems when you start
>   a .NET Framework application, see the "Reinstall any custom .NET
>   Framework assembly performance counters" section in this article.